# Excel VBA: attach files to email without full file name

Tags: excel, outlook, vba

I have to distribute files by email to hundreds of people on a monthly basis. I'm attempting to write a macro that will do this automatically for me. So far, i've got it to create the emails, automatically fill in the body, subject line, and the receipients. I need to be able to get it to automatically attach each persons file to the email. The file names contain the last 6 digits of their account number. I get a report of all of the account numbers i need to send files out to. Is there anyway that i can use those 6 digits to search for the file, and attach it using VBA?

For Example:

say my account numbers are S0001234, S0005678, S0009012. my file names are "ABC - 001234", "DEF - 005678", and "GHI - 009012".

I would reference the entire filename manually but they arent always consistent. I can use the full path to the files though.  Can i attach the file somehow by only referencing these 6 digits in VBA?  For instance, search for any files containing these 6 digits? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`Dir()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dk008ty4(v=vs.90).aspx) function within VBA to achieve what you're after.

```
Sub getFileName()
    Dim strFileName As String
    Dim strCustDigits As String
    strCustDigits = "123456"
    strFileName = Dir("C:\Users\lturner\Documents\*" & strCustDigits & "*")
End Sub
```

`strFileName` will return the the full name (including file format extension) of your workbook.

The asterisk either side of the `strCustDigits` variable denotes that the filename can have anything either side of the digits; it will return the first file it finds within the provided folder, which has the `strCustDigits` variable within it's name.

**EDIT: Updated for additional question asked in comments.**

If you have multiple files, you can loop through each file in a folder (which contains the specified digits) by using the below.

```
Sub getFileNameLoop()
    Dim strFileName As String, strCustDigits As String
    strCustDigits = "123456"
    strFileName = Dir("C:\Users\lturner\Documents\*" & strCustDigits & "*")
    Do While Len(strFileName) > 0
        ' Perform action with file which contains the provided digits
        Debug.Print strFileName
        strFileName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

For further reading on how the `Dir()` function works, please see [here](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vba-dir-function/).

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I'll give this a try.

Comment: suppose i have multiple files with this "123456" in the file name.  how to i go about capturing all of them?

Comment: I've updated my answer - the code will now get all file names in the folder which contain the specified 6 digits.